# In WPF, how to clear DataBinding in a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am using WPFToolKit DataGrid in my application. I have bound the DataGrid to a XMlDocument.
The grid displays the Data from XML. I have to remove all the bindings in DataGrid and reset it during some event.

**Now my question is how do I remove the DataBinding between DataGrid and XMLDocument.**

I have tried something like this ::

```
dg.SetValue(DataGrid.BindingGroupProperty, null); //doesn't work
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line solved my problem ::

```
  BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(dg);
```

Answer (score 6):

To undo a binding in WPF, simply set the property that was previously bound to a some other value.  In the case of `DataGrid`, its data is usually bound to the `ItemsSource` property so setting that to null will remove its previous binding.  But if you have any other properties in the `DataGrid` that are bound, you will have to set those to "unbound" values as well.  Which ones will depend on your situation.  But in your example the code would be:

```
dg.ItemsSource = null;
```

Comment: Would I put this in my viewmodel? I have function that should clear datagrid if user presses save or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dataGrid.DataContext to null or an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me.  What works for me if binding:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
dataGrid.Items.Clear();
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

If not binding:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
dataGrid.Items.Clear();
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```